# In java reactive programming: How to convert Flux<Object> to List<Object> without block()

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I have a use case to convert `Flux<TestClass>` to `List<TestClass>` without the block method.

```
List<TestClass> arrLst= new ArrayList<>();
Flux<TestClass> flx = Flux.just(new TestClass("1", "one"), new TestClass("2", "Two"));

arrLst= flx.collectList().share().block();
System.out.println(arrLst);
```

now I want the `List<TestClass>` without `block();` I tried but was not able to resolve it.

Comment: It is impossible to get a concrete list from a flux without block. A flux is a future, you need to block to wait in the list to exist. The question is instead, why do you need the list?

Comment: as @Toerktumlare mentioned you could not get non-reactive response from the  reactive code without blocking and to be honest it doesn't make sense. With `collectList` you could transform `Flux<TestClass>` to `Mono< List<TestClass>>`

Comment: Actually i want to modify a Json response to collection of json object and Array.

like: {
    "name": "sunil",
    "address": "pune",
    "pin": "123456"
},
{
    "name": "sunil",
    "address": "delhi",
    "pin": "100000"
}


*******************

Now i want the response like 
{
    "name": "sunil",
    "details": [
        {
            "address": "pune",
            "pin": "123456"
        },
        {
            "address": "delhi",
            "pin": "100000"
        }
    ]
}